# INSERT from a SELECT with WHERE - IF EXISTS?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, insert, where-clause

I have the following INSERT

```
INSERT INTO `tbl_productcategorylink` 
(`pcl_p_id`, `pcl_cat_id`, `pcl_orderby`) 
    SELECT 
     `p_id` AS pcl_p_id,
     (SELECT `cat_id` FROM `tbl_categories` WHERE 
       CASE
          WHEN `tbl_products`.`p_gender` = 'female' THEN
               `cat_url_tag` = 'womens' 
          ELSE
           `cat_url_tag` = 'mens'
       END
     LIMIT 1) AS pcl_cat_id,
     1 AS pcl_orderby
FROM `tbl_products` 
WHERE `tbl_products`.`p_gender` = 'female' OR `tbl_products`.`p_gender` = 'male';
```

This is to add a link between a category and a product, any products with `p_gender` set as 'male' are added to the 'mens' category and similarly for the 'female' category.

How can I do this but only if a row doesn't already exist for the given product?

I essentially need to add something to my `WHERE` clause to determine if a row already exists:

```
 AND `exists` IS NULL
```

I have attempted to create this `exists` column in the `SELECT` part of the query, but this messes up the column count and makes the `INSERT` fail.

Has any suggestions on to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
INSERT 
  tbl_productcategorylink 
  (pcl_p_id, pcl_cat_id, pcl_orderby) 
SELECT 
  p.p_id, c.cat_id, 1
FROM 
  tbl_products p
  INNER JOIN tbl_categories c ON c.cat_url_tag = CASE p.p_gender 
                                                 WHEN 'female' THEN 'womens' 
                                                 ELSE 'mens' END
WHERE 
  p.p_gender IN ('female', 'male')
  AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM tbl_productcategorylink WHERE pcl_p_id = p.p_id
  )
```

Comment: a slight amend to the `NOT EXISTS` was this `AND pcl_cat_id = c.cat_id` as a product may already be in the table `tbl_productcategorylink` but in another category. Thanks again.

Comment: @jakenoble: Yes, I thought about adding something like that, but then decided that I could not know for sure whether this would be right or wrong for you. Apparently, you were able to figure that out yourself. :-) My point was more that you can JOIN on expressions which makes the SQL statement a lot simpler and more straight-forward than your original one.

Answer (score 1):

Try a NOT EXISTS in the WHERE clause:

```
INSERT INTO `tbl_productcategorylink` 
(`pcl_p_id`, `pcl_cat_id`, `pcl_orderby`) 
    SELECT 
     `p_id` AS pcl_p_id,
     (SELECT `cat_id` FROM `tbl_categories` WHERE 
       CASE
          WHEN `tbl_products`.`p_gender` = 'female' THEN
               `cat_url_tag` = 'womens' 
          ELSE
           `cat_url_tag` = 'mens'
       END
     LIMIT 1) AS pcl_cat_id,
     1 AS pcl_orderby
FROM `tbl_products` 
WHERE `tbl_products`.`p_gender` = 'female' OR `tbl_products`.`p_gender` = 'male'
     AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `tbl_productcategorylink` WHERE `pcl_p_id` = `tbl_products`.`p_id`);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `INSERT IGNORE` to continue if the key exists. Assuming that there is a unique key on a column(s).

Answer (score 0):

"Insert Ignore" is not efficient when the same SQL is re-executed at a later time, as it will attempt to re-insert ALL records.  You MUST limit attempts to Insert to the smallest quantity possible, for best system performance.

Using sub-select queries is also inefficient, a "LEFT JOIN" is nearly always faster when working with large data sets.  Sub-select queries become horrible in the SELECT clause.  Use 'IFNULL()' in the SELECT clause around the fields from a LEFT JOINed table to provide default values for the missing/NULL records.

Tomalak's answer works, but here is a pure 'LEFT JOIN' example.

```
INSERT INTO tbl_productcategorylink (p_pid, pcl_cat_id, pcl_orderby )
SELECT prod.p_pid, IFNULL( cat.cat_id,0 ), 1 AS pcl_orderby
  FROM tbl_products                  AS prod 
  LEFT JOIN tbl_categories           AS cat  ON cat.cat_url_tag = IF(prod.p_gender='female','womans','mens')
  LEFT JOIN tbl_productcategorylink  AS pcl  ON pcl.pcl_p_id = prod.p_id
 WHERE prod.p_gender IN ('female','male')
   AND pcl.pcl_p_id IS NULL -- Optimizes to faster "NOT EXISTS IN (Select ... From pcl )"
```

This re-write is assuming that tbl_categories has 2 specific records: 'womans' and 'mens'.
Notice the 'where' clause contains the "pcl_p_pid IS NULL" which optimizes to a faster version of "NOT EXISTS IN (Select * From tbl_productcategorylink ... ) " when working with very large datasets.

The Sub-select queries do one of two things:
a) creates a temporary table.
b) performs a 'look-up' into the sub-selected table for EACH record that COULD be in it, as the database walks through the primary 'From' table. This is exaggerated into horrible performance when a sub-select is in the 'SELECT' clause.

LEFT JOINs use the already efficient JOIN logic the database provides, with allowance for missing records.

-- J Jorgenson --